# Centre an image in a wordpress .php file

Tags: php, css

I'm sure this is simple but can anyone please help me find the correct code to centre the image in the below code

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_on_add_to_cart_button');

function add_content_on_add_to_cart_button() {
    
      echo "<img src='image.png' width=70% >"; 
}
```

For context, this code is currently being used in a wordpress websites functions.php file. It is calling woocommerce hooks.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `style` attribute within the `img` tag and use `margin: 0 auto` to center it horizontally (making a `display: block` definition necessary):

```
echo "<img src='image.png' style='display:block;margin: 0 auto;width: 70%;'>" ;
```

Or  –  in case of your given 70% width – just use `margin-left: 15%` within that `style` attribute instead of `margin: 0 auto`